# sap ui5 object header binding

Tags: javascript, java, data-binding, sapui5

i have set a global model for a list item as below

in controller init  method

```
var data = {
        A1: [
            {"id":"1","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":90 },
            {"id":"2","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":93  },
            {"id":"3","Type":"Resolution Time PM","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":96 },
            {"id":"4","Type":"Resolution Time BS","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":70  },
            {"id":"5","Type":"Resolution Time SCI","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":83 },
            {"id":"6","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":90 },
            {"id":"7","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":93  },
            {"id":"8","Type":"Resolution Time PM","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":96 },
            {"id":"9","Type":"Resolution Time BS","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":70  },
            {"id":"10","Type":"Resolution Time SCI","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":83 },
            {"id":"11","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":90 },
            {"id":"12","Type":"Incidents","Ticket":"P1-P2","value":93  }]
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
    oModel.setData(data);  
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,'model_tickets');
    this.List_tickets.setModel(oModel);
    this.List_tickets.bindAggregation("items","/A1",this.List_ticketsTemplate);
```

in view createcontent

```
    oController.List_tickets = new sap.m.List("List_tickets",{}),
        oController.List_ticketsTemplate = new sap.m.ObjectListItem("tickets",{
        title : "{Type}",
        number: "{value}"
         press : oController.NavtoTicketDetails,
        attributes : [new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
        text : "{Ticket}",
            })],
```

onpress event of Listitem the app navigates to object header page where more details of the list item is displayed where id of list  is passed as attribute in routing in other page

how can be filter the global model for selected id and assign to object header basically binding the object header with selected list item values.

Comment: What is not happening ? What is the question ?

Comment: how can we filter the global model for a given id  and assign to sap.m.ObjectHeader basically binding the sap.m.ObjectHeader with selected id .

Comment: Have you implemented `oController.NavtoTicketDetails` ?

Comment: yes... i am able to pass the id to next page with object header control also

Comment: You will also have to read the JSON model again..

Comment: how can we basically filter the global json model  and set data  to Object header control ?

Comment: Once page is navigated, you lose the `model` data..

Comment: The question is how can we filter a global json model stored in sap ui core and bind the data in sap.m.object header control in UI5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110877/discussion-between-user3349850-and-rayon).

Answer (score 1):

You say you can get the id. Then you should bind the object header page to the selected item. (You could specifically bind the list too if you prefer).

```
this.getView().bindElement("model_tickets>/A1/" + id);
```

Also not that the syntax of your bindings should be prefixed by the named model name:

```
...
        title : "{model_tickets>Type}",
        number: "{model_tickets>value}"
...
        text : "{model_tickets>Ticket}",
```

Hope this helps